# my boxLayout components are getting cropped from the window

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, boxlayout

I am making a view with several sliders and buttons, but it is getting cut off by the window, even when I expand the window manually! I am using a box layout, and my friend is doing the same assignment, but somehow his program allows him to fit as many sliders as he wants, and the sliders just move closer and closer together as he makes the height of the window smaller. However, mind is cutting off the last three sliders, even if I expand the window. Here is the code:

```
 public PlayerChefView(int belt_size) {
    this.belt_size = belt_size;
    listeners = new ArrayList<ChefViewListener>();
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    //setLayout(new GridLayout(10,4));

    JLabel colorSelectionLabel = new JLabel("Plate color:", JLabel.CENTER);
    add(colorSelectionLabel);
    String[] colorSelection = {"Blue", "Red", "Green", "Gold"};
    colorBox = new JComboBox(colorSelection);
    colorBox.addActionListener(this);
    add(colorBox);

    JLabel goldPriceLabel = new JLabel("Gold plate price:", JLabel.CENTER);
    add(goldPriceLabel);
    priceSlider = new JSlider(500, 1000, 750);
    Hashtable labelTable = new Hashtable();
    labelTable.put(new Integer(500), new JLabel("$5.00"));
    labelTable.put(new Integer (600), new JLabel("$6.00"));
    labelTable.put(new Integer(700), new JLabel("$7.00"));
    labelTable.put(new Integer(800), new JLabel("$8.00"));
    labelTable.put(new Integer(900) , new JLabel("$9.00"));
    labelTable.put(new Integer(1000), new JLabel("$10.00"));
    //slider.setSnapToTicks(true);
    priceSlider.setLabelTable(labelTable);
    priceSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(100);
    priceSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
    priceSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
    add(priceSlider);

    JLabel positionLabel = new JLabel("Plate position:", JLabel.CENTER);
    add(positionLabel);
    Integer[] positions = new Integer[belt_size];
    for (Integer i = 1; i<=belt_size; i++){
        positions[i - 1] = i;
    }
    positionBox = new JComboBox(positions);
    positionBox.addActionListener(this);
    add(positionBox);


    JLabel sashimiOrNigiriLabel = new JLabel("Would you like to make "
            + "Sashimi or Nigiri?", JLabel.CENTER);
    add(sashimiOrNigiriLabel);
    String[] sashimiOrNigiri = {"Sashimi", "Nigiri" };
    sashimiOrNigiriBox = new JComboBox(sashimiOrNigiri);
    sashimiOrNigiriBox.addActionListener(this);
    add(sashimiOrNigiriBox);

    JLabel seafoodTypeLabel = new JLabel("For sashimi or Nigiri ONLY, what seafood?", JLabel.CENTER);
    add(seafoodTypeLabel);
    String[] seafood = {"Tuna", "Salmon", "Eel", 
            "Crab", "Shrimp"};
    seafoodTypeBox = new JComboBox(seafood);
    seafoodTypeBox.addActionListener(this);
    add(seafoodTypeBox);

    JButton makeSashimiOrNigiri = new JButton("Create sashimi/nigiri!");
    //System.out.println(colorBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
    makeSashimiOrNigiri.setActionCommand("sashimi/nigiri");
    makeSashimiOrNigiri.addActionListener(this);
    add(makeSashimiOrNigiri);
    JLabel blankLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.RIGHT);
    add(blankLabel);


    JLabel avacadoLabel = new JLabel("The following sliders are for rolls only: select avacado amt. (oz.)", JLabel.LEFT);
    add(avacadoLabel);
    avocadoSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 150, 0);
    amountLabels = new Hashtable();
    amountLabels.put(new Integer(0), new JLabel("0.0"));
    amountLabels.put(new Integer (25), new JLabel(".25"));
    amountLabels.put(new Integer(50), new JLabel(".50"));
    amountLabels.put(new Integer(75), new JLabel(".75"));
    amountLabels.put(new Integer(100) , new JLabel("1.00"));
    amountLabels.put(new Integer(125), new JLabel("1.25"));
    amountLabels.put(new Integer(150), new JLabel("1.50"));
    avocadoSlider.setLabelTable(amountLabels);
    avocadoSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(25);
    avocadoSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
    avocadoSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
    add(avocadoSlider);

    JLabel crabLabel = new JLabel("select crab amt. (oz.)", JLabel.LEFT);
    add(crabLabel);
    crabSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 150, 0);
    crabSlider.setLabelTable(amountLabels);
    crabSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(25);
    crabSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
    crabSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
    add(crabSlider);

    JLabel eelLabel = new JLabel("select eel amt. (oz.)", JLabel.LEFT);
    add(eelLabel);
    eelSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 150, 0);
    eelSlider.setLabelTable(amountLabels);
    eelSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(25);
    eelSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
    eelSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
    add(eelSlider);

    JLabel riceLabel = new JLabel("select rice amt. (oz.)",             JLabel.LEFT);
    add(riceLabel);
    riceSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 150, 0);
    riceSlider.setLabelTable(amountLabels);
    riceSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(25);
    riceSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
    riceSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
    add(riceSlider);

    JLabel salmonLabel = new JLabel("select salmon amt. (oz.)", JLabel.LEFT);
    add(salmonLabel);
    salmonSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 150, 0);
    salmonSlider.setLabelTable(amountLabels);
    salmonSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(25);
    salmonSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
    salmonSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
    add(salmonSlider);

    JLabel seaweedLabel = new JLabel("select seaweed amt. (oz.)", JLabel.LEFT);
    add(seaweedLabel);
    seaweedSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 150, 0);
    seaweedSlider.setLabelTable(amountLabels);
    seaweedSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(25);
    seaweedSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
    seaweedSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
    add(seaweedSlider);

    JLabel shrimpLabel = new JLabel("select shrimp amt. (oz.)", JLabel.LEFT);
    add(shrimpLabel);
    shrimpSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 150, 0);
    shrimpSlider.setLabelTable(amountLabels);
    shrimpSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(25);
    shrimpSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
    shrimpSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
    add(shrimpSlider);

    JLabel tunaLabel = new JLabel("select tuna amt. (oz.)", JLabel.LEFT);
    add(tunaLabel);
    tunaSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 150, 0);
    tunaSlider.setLabelTable(amountLabels);
    tunaSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(25);
    tunaSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
    tunaSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
    add(tunaSlider);
```

See this screenshot to see what I mean:
[Note that the slider labels are getting cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfs8x.png)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). That code has 7 sliders and many labels. Can it be reproduced with two sliders and no labels? 2) Please **read** the helpful tag pop-ups before adding them to a question. This problem has *nothing* to do with the [tag:box] tag! 3) As far as the screenshot goes, tit could be summed up by the words *"The sliders are being cut off at the bottom of the GUI"*, but see also See also [How to create great screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734/155831)

Comment: Okay, thanks i guess? but anyways I figured it out myself, I switched it to grid layout with 0 in the row position